# How to write command lines

Tags: command-line, executable

After my first login on Ubuntu 13 it tells me about copyrights and warranty then drops down to:

`Username@Hostname:~$_`

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most people use a GUI (graphical user interface) to operate their machine; but versions like server use a CLI (command line interface) as its more efficient (faster for knowledgeable operators, and far faster for the machine).  Usually after login most people are in their DEsktop (a flavor of GUI) not a CLI. The ~ means you're in your directory (a shorthand), but if the machine is going to be used long term upgrade to a version that is supported (13.04 & 13.10 are EOL; 14.04LTS (2014 April release) is the oldest with free support)

Comment: I suspect that s/he thinks he *did* install a desktop version with a GUI, but that the graphics driver or some such crashed. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely broad, and I would recommend visiting a third-party site like linuxacademy.com to learn about the basics of GNU/Linux, UNIX, and BSD.  However, here are some basics to start with to get around.  Type in each of these commands in order and see what happens.

```
cd
ls
mkdir test
ls
pwd
touch file.txt file2.txt
ls
rm file2.txt
ls
```

After doing this, then type `man cd` and `man ls` etc., and read the manual pages about each of these commands.  To get out of the manual pages type `q`.

When you are done exploring, visit this site - http://man.he.net/man1 - and ready every chapter until your mind explodes.  After that, please note how to exit.  Depending on whether this is a server or shell emulator, these options will help you in quitting, restarting, or shutting down.

```
exit
sudo reboot
sudo poweroff
```

Best luck in *nix land.

Comment: Thanks everything helps! Im gonna get it...Listen got another question for you guys....I got a tablet RCA rct6973w43. android 6.0.....well under the Kernel version 3.14.o+     it says (lxz@ubuntu 195 #278/ SMP PREEMPT) does this mean anything to anyone.....I want to root the tablet and I figured if it has a Linux/Ubuntu kernel it would have to be open source....right?

Comment: Yes, android uses the Linux kernel which is #freesoftware.